# WLAN does not work after hibernate in HP Envy

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, hibernate

Resume after hibernate works fine except that WLAN does not recover. WLAN works fine after cold boot.

`ifconfig` shows that before hibernate WLAN works fine: `wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>` etc. but no WLAN after hibernate. (Ethernet is there before and after hibernate.)

I tried `lshw` before and after hibernate. Here is before hibernate (excerpt):

```
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: e3
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:44 memory:c6100000-c61fffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
            vendor: Broadcom Limited
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
            logical name: wlo1
            version: 01
            serial: [REMOVED]
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:18 memory:c6100000-c6107fff
```

But after hibernate WLAN seems to be DISABLED:

```
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: e3
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:44 memory:c6100000-c61fffff
       *-network DISABLED
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
            vendor: Broadcom Limited
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
            logical name: wlo1
            version: 01
            serial: [REMOVED]
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:18 memory:c6100000-c6107fff
```

The network manager seems to be dead and Wifi connections do not respond. I tried to restart network manager using command line without success.

The problem has persisted all this 1.5 years and I have had Ubuntu versions 15.04 through 16.10. I also reinstalled 16.04. No luck. Could anyone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: The Power Management systems handles hibernate/wakeup. Read `man pm-action` and look at `/etc/pm/` to see which script to adjust.